# when I go to xampp/php/ only I Found phi.ini-development and php.ini-production

Tags: php, xampp

[but when Igo to xampp/php/  onlyIFound phi.ini-development and php.ini-production Using XMPP server for PHP development and want to edit the php.ini file; this is my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85sGv.png)

Answer (score 1):

`php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` are just example files. The first one has default values dedicated to development / testing purposes, which the latter one is intended for production.

You should rename one of them, based on your needs, to `php.ini`.

Comment: I trying to install Xdebug and I can't

Answer (score 0):

Make a php.ini-development( or php.ini-production ) duplicate. Then rename it with `php.ini`.

Comment: I try and said that php.ini is already there and if  I want to change it.??

Comment: I found you had already pho.ini there. You os hide the file extension name.